# <h1> to <h6> tags are not being displayed in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've encountered an extremely weird error on Google Chrome, when using the 'Roboto' font by Google, the h1 to h6 tags are not being rendered on the screen.

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome, I'm lost and have no idea what is going on - has anybody experienced this error? This is my code for h2, h3 tags:

```
h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[comparison http://domcorso.me/0/2/h1h6.png](http://domcorso.me/0/2/h1h6.png)

Comment: Check your developer tools, under networking/resources. Are the fonts being loaded correctly? Do you have a local (corrupted?) copy of Roboto installed?

Comment: Hey Terry, the font is being loaded correctly as the paragraphs are using the same @font-face as the header tags. I'm starting to think this is just a rendering issue with my software/hardware and Chrome itself

Comment: Maybe some Chrome extensions are affecting rendering. Have you tried disabling them?

Comment: Try to recreate the problem in a snippet in the question, or in a jsfiddle. Or if that won't work, provide a link to the website (but only as a last resort).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any style applied to your headers (like color:#fff;). Roboto renders ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sw1hsakx/

Comment: UPDATE: h1-h6 tags automatically include 'font-weight: bold' - after setting the 'font-weight' property to 'normal', it works. A bit of a strange one, it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using Roboto Light instead of Roboto regular like Alvaro was using in his JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: h1-h6 tags automatically include 'font-weight: bold' - after setting the 'font-weight' property to 'normal', it works. A bit of a strange one, it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using Roboto Light instead of Roboto regular like Alvaro was using in his JSfiddle.

Comment: A font-weight of '600' or higher doesn't render

Comment: You should edit the question and put this info in. Answers are meant for providing solutions, not extra info to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:  You can put in any text you want int that font face="calibri".

```html
<font face="calibri">
<h1>Whater the text you want</h1>
```